# Regarding to How Increase Mpdf library Execution Fast with php

Tags: php, mpdf

I am a web developer and I am using the [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/) Library to generate PDF files. I would like to generate a PDF file with about 2000 - 3000 pages in PHP. The mPDF library needs a lot of time to generate the PDF file and I hit the maximum server time out.

How could I increase the execution?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things i know of that can help you.

a. In the mpdf installation directory you will find the file **compress.php**. This will allow you to create a new version of mpdf.php - a lighter version. When you run the **compress.php** you will get to choose which libraries/functions you need to have for your pdf - discard what you don't need. Backup the original file first.

b. On the top of your scrpt add: `ini_set("memory_limit","256M");`. Change it to suit your needs - this one will allow you to use 256MB of memory

**Edit:** (about compress.php usage)

Run the file. Follow instruction on screen.
First time you run it it will tell you that a file is missing. No worries. Copy & Rename original mpdf.php into mpdf_source.php, upload it to installation directory. Then refresh your page.
You will get many options on what to include in your pdf. Choose what you want.

Backup mpdf.php first.

Comment: i hope these tps will assist you. 2000 pages are tough

Comment: Can you Explain me about compress.php.  according to your given first thing (a) ,so how to work this file

Comment: how to increase performance for  php execution ,my some code take time but i have large code so i am shareing my code in different -different comments

Comment: a. In the mpdf installation directory you will find the file compress.php. This will allow you to create a new version of mpdf.php - a lighter version. When you run the compress.php you will get to choose which libraries/functions you need to have for your pdf - discard what you don't need. Backup the original file first.

so how to work with compress.php file please give me reply

Comment: @user3811650 i have edit my answer, Please see edit section

Comment: that means we have to rename mpdf.php file,and after that we have to run code ?

Comment: if i renamed mpdf.php file , then it will unable to work for ganerate pdf file
we are facing problem Warning: require_once(/path for mpdf.php file)
so please give me reply how to improve with fasr execution for my php with mysql script

Comment: @user3811650 i said Copy & Rename, not just rename

Comment: yes i also have backup,i have one another copy for mpdf.php file,after copy i renamed mpdf.php file

Comment: how to run file  compress.php because its intrenal file

Comment: hello, @andrew I have rename mpdf to mpdf_source but i am getting error ERROR - Could not find mpdf_source.php file in current directory. Please rename mpdf.php as mpdf_source.php
so how to solve this problem

Comment: hope these tps will assist you. 2000 pages are tough –  andrew 3 hours ago

but please give me steps  because i am facing problem to ganerate pdf with mpdf_source.php file it is giving error

Comment: @user3811650 i have given you everything i know. The error message says what to do,.,. upload the file in root directory of the mpdf folder

Comment: ,i have to copy mpdf.php file then  after copy we have to paste this file and after paste we have to rename this file with name mpdf_source.php  then we have to run  **compress.php** file after that what we have to do ?

Comment: Thanks in advance
@ **andrew** i have followed steps using  **compress.php** and **mpdf_source.php**  to ganerate new mpdf.php file but i got error 
error message **ERROR - Could not find mpdf_source.php file in current directory. Please rename mpdf.php as mpdf_source.php**

**So what i do for increase fast execution  for fast mpdf library**

Comment: You can always try to read the official forum of your library, with detailed information on how to accomplish what you want.